# Cleaner if statement sequence in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am a bit of a newbie so please go easy on me. I wanted to know if there was a way to shorten these if statement chains like the one shown below in C++.

```
int offset;
    
string S;
cin >> S;

if(S == "mon")
{ offset = 0; }
else if(S == "tues")
{ offset = 1; }
else if(S == "wed")
{ offset = 2; }
else if(S == "thurs")
{ offset = 3; }
else if(S == "fri")
{ offset = 4; }
else if(S == "sat")
{ offset = 5; }
else if(S == "sun")
{ offset = 6; }
```

Comment: What about a `switch` statement?

Comment: @AristotelisV One cannot switch on string in C++.

Comment: You could have a `std::map<std::string, int>` or `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` to use as a lookup table and then do `offset = lookup_table[S];`

Comment: Make an array of the strings, a loop to get the offset directly.

Comment: To be fair, I'd just put it into a function as is. `map` solutions are good, but it feels like an overkill here.

Comment: @Déjàvu, searching through an array with a loop isn't the worst idea in _this specific case_, but it wouldn't scale to a larger application. Lookup in a `std::map` is O(log n) while the looping over an array approach would be O(n).

Comment: `std::unordered_map` is generally an O(1) lookup... (worst case O(n)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

```
std::map<std::string, int> m { 
  {"mon", 0}, {"tues", 1}, {"wed", 2}, {"thurs", 3},
  {"fri", 4}, {"sat", 5}, {"sun", 6}
};

std::string s;
std::cin >> s;

int offset = m.at(s);
```

If s is not a valid key, the [std::out_of_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception will be thrown. You might handle that by putting a try block in a loop and gathering input until you get a valid key, as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <map>

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, int> m { 
    {"mon", 0}, {"tues", 1}, {"wed", 2}, {"thurs", 3},
    {"fri", 4}, {"sat", 5}, {"sun", 6}
  };

  std::string s;

  while (true) {
    try {
      std::cin >> s;
      int offset = m.at(s);
      std::cout << offset << std::endl;
      break;
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range e) {
      std::cerr << "Invalid input: " << s << std::endl;      
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

You *could* also refactor your original code to use `? :` (the actual name is somewhat debatable). Of course, this requires us to provide an `else` case, so let's go with `-1`.

```
int offset =
  S == "mon"   ? 0 :
  S == "tues"  ? 1 :
  S == "wed"   ? 2 :
  S == "thurs" ? 3 :
  S == "fri"   ? 4 :
  S == "sat"   ? 5 :
  S == "sun"   ? 6 : -1;
```